# sending application arguments on a docker-compose for a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to do something super simple/

Should be that easy but seems like I am forgetting something...

I made a simple application.

It has properties on a yml file, like this:

then I create a `Dockerfile.yml`

It receives parameters when running... like this:

```
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["java", "-server", "$JAVA_OPTS", "-jar", "helloworld.jar", "$APP_ARGS" ]
```

It should override some parameters, like the `${KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC}`

when I run it on a docker-compose I made this:

```
hello-world:
    image: my-docker-image
    ports:
    -  8080:8080
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERS: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC: test
```

Then it fails because the KAFKA_INPUT_TOPIC default value has an invalid character, what it means it fails to set the new parameter `test` .

I have to say when I set default values it works fine, but doesn't work for me that... I have no idea then how to send it as a parameter, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: how do you read the env?

Comment: inside the app with a @Value

Comment: are you using spring 3.1+?

Comment: yes, spring boot 2 actually

Comment: can you `exec`  in your container and `env`?